# Aggregations on most recent document in group using elasticsearch

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, aggregate

Suppose there are several documents per person that contain values:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "value": 1,
  "timestamp": 2014-06-15
}

{
  "name": "John",
  "value": 2,
  "timestamp": 2014-06-16
}

{
  "name": "Sam",
  "value": 2,
  "timestamp": 2014-06-15
}

{
  "name": "Sam",
  "value": 3,
  "timestamp": 2014-06-16
}
```

1. How do I get a list of the most recent documents for each person?
2. How do I get an average of the values for the list of the most recent documents for each person? Given the sample data, this would be 2.5, not 2.

Is there some combination of buckets and metrics that could achieve this result? Will I need to implement a custom aggregator as part of a plugin, or must this sort of computation be performed in memory?

Comment: couldn't you just sort on the timestamp field ? This seems to be a case of relevance rather that aggregations and sorting would do the trick here

Comment: 5 years past, and I have exactly the same problem. Have you solved this, Shaun?

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to find the most recent **`persons`** try something like this:

```js
"aggs": {
    "personName": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "name",
            "size": 5,
            "order": {"timeCreated": "desc"}
        },
        "aggs": {
            "timeCreated": {
                "max": {"field": "timestamp"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you make the size 5 @Nelu Malancea

Comment: @emarel, because I only needed to display the newest 5.

Answer (score 1):

The second operation is just an aggregation, and to get the average of the `value` field you could try something like:

```
curl -XPOST "http://DOMAIN:9200/your/data/_search" -d'
{
   "size": 0, 
   "aggregations": {
      "the_name": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "name",
            "order": {
               "value_avg": "desc"
            }
         },
         "aggregations": {
            "value_avg": {
               "avg": {
                  "field": "value"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

To achieve a solution for your first issue I would recommend you to order the response by date, and then in your project ignore a term when you have another with the same name (meaning filter the data after the response of ES)

Comment: All right. Having to manually filter documents on the client or via a plugin (to avoid network overhead) is something I would like to avoid, but it doesn't seem like that's possible in this case.

Comment: You could make a small python script (python or any other language), and make the querys through the script. Something like: `receive_query_string-> make the query -> get the response -> Filter the response -> return desired results`